# cannot load or create windows phone application vs 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I cannot create or load any windows phone application using vs 2013 it gives me the import failed error .
when I try to reload it . it gives me this error

[image]

it happened after a system restore which I had to do because of another visual studio problem
. i have tried repairing and reinstalling visual studio but nothing happens . what should I do ?

Comment: Check whether you do have the v8.0 as mentioned above in the given path in your C drive? This seems that when you're trying to import a WP8 app to your VS 2013, you're getting this issue?

Comment: Try to uninstall then reinstall the Window Phone SDK ...